# React Query one loading spinner for 3 child components

Tags: reactjs, react-query

I have three components, each using the same two queries (custom hooks):

```
  const {
    data: survey,
    isLoading: isSurveyLoading,
    isError: isSurveyError,
  } = useSurveyInfo(id);

  const {
    data: responses,
    isLoading: isResponsesLoading,
    isError: isResponsesError,
  } = useResponses(id);
```

In each of these 3 components, I'm showing a loading spinner in the case of `isLoading`
[image: loading spinners]

How do I show one loading spinner for all three components?

I know I could use the queries in the parent component and pass props to children. But to eliminate prop drilling, I am calling each query in the child component (which seems to be best practice).

Is there a way to show **one** loading spinner when **any** of the 3 child components is loading?

Comment: prop drilling itself is not a bad practice, especially if it is only a few level drops.

Comment: You could use `useContext` or `recoiljs`, in the parent. and then toggle it from each children so it has one boolean value. then you can decide which child to show the spinner.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Suspense` is made for this, but it's still experimental

https://tanstack.com/query/v4/docs/guides/suspense

Answer (score 1):

One of beauties of react-query is that it allows you to render multiple components that relay on the same data and updates all the components at the same time since they all rely on the same provider.

But now the job to make it look good on the website is on us.

I suggest not rendering the loader from the 2 lower components in the page.

Or if it makes no sense to have a content less component, you can always return null from the components.

```
const SecondAndTheirComponents = () => {
  const { isLoading: isResponsesLoading } = useResponses(id);

  if (isResponsesLoading) {
    return null;
  }
  return (
    <Content
      ...
     />
  );
};
```

Or better yet: I would recommend looking into adding skeletons when you are loading data. This way you could save the space for all component and avoid jumpiness when data is returned to the browser.

You can checkout the skeletons by Material-ui (both v3 and v4 work perfectly fro me) [v4 skeletons-material](https://v4.mui.com/components/skeleton/#skeleton)

Answer (score 0):

According to your first question loading one spinner for all three components, you can use if else condition of reactjs, for example-

```
{
isResponseLoading?
isSurveyLoading?
<RunSpinnerCode/>
:
null
}
```

As shown in the above we can check two and even more condition. If first one is loaded, then we check for second one and so on..
Hope you like the answer if you still face any issue, just lemme know.
Thanks

Comment: Thank you, but the issue is I'm calling useQuery in the child components (3 separate  components) and not in the parent component

Comment: Can you share code on sandbox or here.. I think i will solve your query.. Thanks